# find with -execdir

Tags: shell, files, find, directory, directory-structure

When I run `find` with `-execdir` I don't get the results I was expecting.

For example:

```
mkdir -p a/b/c
find . -type d -execdir touch foo \;
$ tree a
a
├── b
│   ├── c
│   └── foo
└── foo
```

Directory `c` does not contain a `foo` file.
How do I get `find` to visit and do something locally in each directory?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For every matching file (i.e. every directory), `find` switches to the directory that contains it (i.e. its parent directory) and executes the specified command. Since the command doesn't use the name of the match, it's never going to act on all the directories. For this particular directory tree, you're doing

```
(cd . && touch foo)        # because ./a matches
(cd ./a && touch foo)      # because ./a/b matches
(cd ./a/b && touch foo)    # because ./a/b/c matches
```

To create a file in every directory, you can simply use `-exec` instead of `-execdir`, provided your implementation of `find` allows `{}` inside an argument (many do):

```
find . -type d -exec touch '{}/foo' +
```

For POSIX portability, you would need to do the assembling of the directory name and the file base name manually.

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'touch "$0/foo"' {} \;
```

or (slightly faster)

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'for d; do touch "$d/foo"; done' sh {} +
```

Alternatively, you can use bash's recursive wildcard matching. Beware that (unlike the corresponding feature in ksh and zsh, and unlike your `find` command) earlier versions of bash used to recurse under symbolic links to directories.

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/*/; do touch -- "$d/foo"; done
```

A zsh solution:

```
touch ./**/*(/e[REPLY+=/foo])
```

Or:

```
(){ touch $^@/foo; } ./**/*(/)
```

Comment: FYI: `man bash` states under "-c": arguments after command_string are assigned to positional parameters starting with $0, however "for d" will iterate through positional parameters starting with $1.  "_" is text that is assigned to $0 and will not be used.

Comment: $ find -type d -exec touch {}/foo +
find: In ‘-exec ... {} +’ the ‘{}’ must appear by itself, but you specified ‘{}/foo’
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0

Comment: As reported in [the previous comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108216#comment1262878_108300), the command `find . -type d -exec touch {}/foo +` results in a message saying `find: In ‘-exec ... {} +’ the ‘{}’ must appear by itself, but you specified ‘{}/foo’`.
~ * ~
Replacing the ending `+` with `\;` makes it work.
~ * ~
As I understand [this link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=257636),
busybox's `find` runs fine with the `+`
(as a side effect of treating `\;` and `+` interchangeably?),
while this is not the case with GNU's `find`.

Answer (score 7):

The command executes in every directory that contains a matched file. Since `c` doesn't contain a directory, it doesn't match and thus won't be run there.

The solution is to add the directory name to the execdir argument, like so:

```
find . -type d -execdir touch {}/foo \;
```

Answer (score 6):

From [`man find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> `-execdir command {} +`
>
>   Like
>   **`-exec`**
>   ,  but  the  specified  command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file ...

Your matching directory `c` lives in the `b` directory, so that is where the exec is run from. It would work as you expect if you are looking for files instead of directories.

You could probably achieve what you want by sending the directories to `xargs`,
as that will be supplied the full list of directories.